# Xamarin.Forms - Need to have a custom control which takes in multiple views

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I need to have a custom view that will take in multiple views and then display a different view based on my needs. I have created a custom view using a class file and I have created public property of `IList<View>` which looks something like this.

```
public class CustomLayout : ContentView
{
    private IList<View> _childViews = new List<View>();
    public IList<View> ChildViews 
    { 
       get { return _childViews; } set { _childViews = value; } 
    }

    public CustomLayout()
    {
      //If 'ChildViews' count is greater than 0 then process views 
      //and have a custom view as Content.
    }
}
```

And now my xaml looks something like this

```
<controls:CustomLayout BackgroundColor="Pink" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
   <controls:CustomLayout.ChildViews>
      <Frame Height="50" Width="50" BackgroundColor="Yellow"/>
      <Frame Height="50" Width="50" BackgroundColor="Green"/>
      <Frame Height="50" Width="50" BackgroundColor="Red"/>
      <Frame Height="50" Width="50" BackgroundColor="Blue"/>
   </controls:CustomLayout.ChildViews>
</controls:CustomLayout>
```

Now the issue that I am facing is I do not get "set" call for "ChildViews" nor that I get all the views in "ChildViews" when ctor of `CustomLayout` is called.
I have also tried creating `BindableProperty` for "ChildViews" but the same behavior is there.
A very strange thing is that I was trying the same thing a few days back and I was getting a List of Views on ctor of `CustomLayout`. I had to revert the code at that time and now I don't remember what was there in the code so that it was working then.

Lol.

EDIT:

I am really sorry for the incomplete question. By looking at the comment and answer I feel like I need to explain why I need "ChildViews" instead of `TemplateSelector`.

I need to create a CustomLayout like `FlexLayout` and because of that I need all the children accessible by the property "ChildViews". I will write custom logic in the same class which will place all the "ChildViews" in `StackLayout` based on width.

Why I am not using `FlexLayout`? There is an issue in flexlayout that is already reported [this issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/5311). Because of this, there is need for me to create a CustomLayout.

If you have any better way to do this then please suggest that too.!

Comment: A DataTemplateSelector can choose between different views. Subclass that.

Answer (score 0):

Like ToolmakerSteve said, you could use `DataTemplateSelector`.

A simple example for your reference:

```
class DymaicDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
public DataTemplate Tab1Template { get; set; }

public DataTemplate Tab2Template { get; set; }

protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
{
    return ((TabViewModel)item).Header == "Tab1" ? Tab1Template : Tab2Template;

}
}
```

For the whole project, you could refer to the link below. [Load ContentView inside CarouselView in Xamarn forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67270944/load-contentview-inside-carouselview-in-xamarn-forms/67279511#67279511)

For more details, you could check the MS docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector